# Question about the derivation of RC Filters frequency cutoff

Tags: filter, frequency, math, frequency-measurement

We've learned that the operation in RC filters depends on how the capacitor reacts to different frequencies, in other words, the capacitative reactance.

The input is applied in series with a resistor in a "low pass filter" and the output is taken across the capacitor. Basically, this low pass filter passes low frequencies but blocks high frequencies.

I was wondering if anyone can assist me in deriving this expression

$$f = \frac{1}{2 \pi RC}$$

The book gives this curious expression which I hope makes sense to someone: $$v_{out} = v_{in}\frac{X_c}{\sqrt{R^2 + X_c^2}} $$ This is somehow connected to the expression above. I've tried reasoning with voltage dividers, but couldn't get such an expression:

$$v_{in} = I(R + X_{c})$$
$$v_{out} = IX_{c}$$

which gives the expression for the output voltage above. The problem with this "explanation" is that the same formula applies to the "high pass filter" where the input is in series with the capacitor and how could they both have the same output voltage?

Comment: Are you sure the HPF and LPF have the same voltage equations? You should see a difference in the numerator much like a resistance divider equation.

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that in LP filter, the output is across the capacitor, while in HP filter, it is across the resistor . The expression comes from voltage divider and the square root is for magnitude of a complex impedance.

Comment: \$v_{out} = IX_c\$ for LPF and it is \$v_{out} = IR\$ for HPF

Answer (score 1):

"*Basically, this low pass filter passes low frequencies but blocks high frequencies.*"

At first, no lowpass filter can "block high frequencies" - and, in particular, not the most simple first order RC lowpass. Each lowpass only can - increasingly with rising frequencies - attenuate the amplitudes of frequencies above the corner frequency. Please note that the attenuation at this corner frequency is 3db (attenuation factor 1.414).

Secondly, regarding the squareroot expression: Please note that the capacitive impedance is an imaginary expression (Xc=1/jwc) - and, hence, application of the classical voltage divider rule (between R and Xc) leads to a COMPLEX expression for the transfer ratio T(jw) consisting of a real (Re) and an imaginary part (Im).

Then, the magnitude of the transfer function T(jw) (output-to-input ratio) is **|T(jw)|=SQRT(Re²+Im²)** and the phase is **Phi=arctan(Re/Im).**

Setting |T(jw)|=1/1.414=0.7071 and solving for w gives the corner frequency **fc=1/2Pi*RC**.

Regarding **C-R highpass**:
The above described calculation (based on SQRT(2)=1.414) reveals that at the corner frequency w=wc the magnitude of the capacitive resistance (1/wC) is equal to the real resistance (R). Therefore, the first-order C-R highpass has the same corner frequency as the R-C lowpass.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about which component is across the output and just consider the filter as a series connected R and C.

At DC, all the input voltage is across the capacitor and at infinite frequency all the input voltage is across the resistor. At some point the voltages across R and C will be equal in magnitude - this is when |Xc| = R therefore: -

R = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi f C}\$ or put another way: -

f = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi R C}\$

For a 1st order filter the cut-off voltage is precisely the definition of when these two impedances are equal. This applies equally to high-pass and low-pass.